# Theano: Get matrix dimension and value of matrix (SharedVariable)

Tags: python, theano

I would like to know how to retrieve the dimension of a SharedVariable from theano.

This here e.g. does not work:

```
from theano import *
from numpy import *

import numpy as np

w = shared( np.asarray(zeros((1000,1000)), np.float32) )

print np.asarray(w).shape
print np.asmatrix(w).shape
```

and only returns

```
()
(1, 1)
```

I am also interested in printing/retriving the values of a matrix or vector ..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can get the value of a shared variable like this:

```
w.get_value()
```

Then this would work:

```
w.get_value().shape
```

But this will copy the shared variable content. To remove the copy you can use the borrow parameter like this:

```
w.get_value(borrow=True).shape
```

But if the shared variable is on the GPU, this will still copy the data from the GPU to the CPU. To don't do this:

```
w.get_value(borrow=True, return_internal_type=True).shape
```

Their is a simpler way to do this, compile a Theano function that return the shape:

```
w.shape.eval()
```

`w.shape` return a symbolic variable. .eval() will compile a Theano function and return the value of shape.

If you want to know more about how Theano handle the memory, check this web page: http://www.deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/aliasing.html

Comment: Good answer. However I would still recommend checking the shape of variables in a manual way since this take huge time if you do it a lot in your code. Have the shape as a variable and keep a track of it throughout the model.